# MVVM: ViewModel is null when trying to load data using LiveData

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-room, android-livedata

So I'm trying to build a simple MVVM interface to load trips from the database retrieved by the ViewModel into my TripFragment. However, I keep getting this error saying that my TripViewModel is null:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.observe(androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner, androidx.lifecycle.Observer)' on a null object reference
```

I can't seem to figure out why it thinks that it's null. I believe the issue is in TripViewModel and has something to do with how the fact that it inherits from AndroidViewModel and that I'm passing the application's context in the constructor.

class TripFragment : Fragment()

```
private var tripViewModel: TripViewModel? = null
private var textViewTripName: TextView? = null

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val view =
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_trip, container, false)

    val recyclerView: RecyclerView = view.recycler_view
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)

    val adapter = TripAdapter()
    recyclerView.adapter = adapter

    tripViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(TripViewModel(activity!!.application)::class.java)


    // This is the line where it crashes, it never executes past this
    tripViewModel!!.getAll().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer<List<Trip>> {
        fun onChanged(trips: List<Trip>) {
            adapter.setTrips(trips)
            Log.d("TripFragment", "Went through observer")
        }
    })

    return view
}
```

class TripViewModel(application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application)

```
private var tripRepository: TripRepository = TripRepository(application)
private var allTrips: LiveData<List<Trip>> = getAll()

fun insert(trip: Trip) {
    tripRepository.insert(trip)
}

fun update(trip: Trip) {
    tripRepository.update(trip)
}

fun delete(trip: Trip) {
    tripRepository.delete(trip)
}

fun clear() {
    tripRepository.clear()
}

fun getAll(): LiveData<List<Trip>> {
    return allTrips
}
```

class TripRepository(application: Application)

```
private lateinit var tripDao: TripDao
private lateinit var allTrips: LiveData<List<Trip>>

init {
    CoroutineScope(IO).launch {
        tripDao = AppDatabase.getDatabase(application.applicationContext).tripDao()
        allTrips = tripDao.getAll()
    }
}

fun insert(trip: Trip) {
    CoroutineScope(IO).launch {
        tripDao.insert(trip)
    }
}

fun update(trip: Trip) {
    CoroutineScope(IO).launch {
        tripDao.update(trip)
    }
}

fun delete(trip: Trip) {
    CoroutineScope(IO).launch {
        tripDao.delete(trip)
    }
}

fun clear() {
    CoroutineScope(IO).launch {
        tripDao.clear()
    }
}

fun getAll(): LiveData<List<Trip>> {
    return allTrips
}
```

Trip entity

```
@Entity
data class Trip(var title: String, var startDate: String, var endDate: String?) {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var tid: Long = 0
}
```

EDIT: I've printed a bunch of debug logs and pinpointed the error at this line in `TripRepository`.

```
init {
    CoroutineScope(IO).launch {
        // tripDao is never assigned properly, 
        tripDao = AppDatabase.getDatabase(application.applicationContext).tripDao()
        allTrips = tripDao.getAll()
    }
}
```

The line `tripDao = AppDatabase.getDatabase(application.applicationContext).tripDao()` causes an error which turns tripDao into a null variable. The problem has something to do with how I fetch the database, so I've attached my AppDatabase class below.

```
@Database(entities = [Trip::class], version = 2, exportSchema = false)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun tripDao(): TripDao

    companion object {
        // Singleton prevents multiple instances of database opening at the
        // same time.
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: AppDatabase? = null

        fun getDatabase(context: Context): AppDatabase {
            val tempInstance = INSTANCE
            if (tempInstance != null) {
                Log.d("AppDatabase", "Returning existing database")
                return tempInstance
            }
            synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    AppDatabase::class.java,
                    "tripweaver_database"
                )
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .build()
                INSTANCE = instance
                Log.d("AppDatabase", "Returning new database")
                return instance
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't post any code where you call `.value` on live data. Can you clarify which line of code is producing the NPE?

Comment: By the way, if you use the fragments ktx library, you can just declare `val tripsViewModel by viewModels<TripViewModel>()` and not have to worry about nullability or having to set it in `onCreateView`.

Comment: @Tenfour04 So I changed something in my code which removed the initial NPE. However, it now executed the next line which then causes a new NPE caused by the observer. I updated the error message in the post. Could you elaborate your alternative solution as I don't quite understand how it works.

Comment: A Java NPE, or Kotlin NPE? Can you show it? By the way, in the line before, you are needlessly instantiating a ViewModel before getting its class. Use `TripViewModel::class.java`, not `TripViewModel(activity!!.application)::class.java`

Comment: It's a Java NPE: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.observe(androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner, androidx.lifecycle.Observer)' on a null object reference`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find the solution to fixing my database access code so I restructured my whole codebase according to the architecture components tutorial by Google on Codelabs. Surely enough this helped me fix the issues I was having. Link for whoever needs this tutorial in the future: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin/#13

Answer (score -2):

In your class `TripViewModel`, you have:

```
private var allTrips: LiveData<List<Trip>> = getAll()

fun getAll(): LiveData<List<Trip>> {
    return allTrips
}
```

So you have a circular arrangement here. `allTrips` is assigned an initial value of whatever `getAll()` returns, but it's calling `getAll()` before `allTrips` is assigned. So you found a way to assign a null to a non-nullable!

Seems like maybe you meant to put `allTrips = tripRepository.getAll()`.

Comment: I made the amendment and now it's giving me the error `kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property tripDao has not been initialized` in my `TripRepository` class. Does this mean that my `TripViewModel` is trying to access the `allTrips` property from `TripRepository` before the init block runs?